# SQL - get name and total sum of rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get "name" from "product", sum of "amount" from "sale" table, and sum of "amount" from "forecast" table

The actual SQL query is:

```
SELECT product.name, sale.amount, forecast.amount
FROM product
LEFT JOIN forecast ON product.id = forecast.product_id
LEFT JOIN sale ON product.id = sale.product_id;
```

But the SQL result looks like this[image: The result]

And the filled tables looks like on this schema[image: Filled tables]

I really don't know how to do this correctly to make my result success, I tried lot of variants.

I also tried this:

```
SELECT product.name, SUM(sale.amount), SUM(forecast.amount) FROM product LEFT JOIN forecast ON product.id = forecast.product_id LEFT JOIN sale ON product.id = sale.product_id WHERE product.id=1
```

But this SQL query gives me values for product.id 1 sales 108 and forecast 90, so that's not correct values..

Comment: Hint: `SUM()` (it's a very clearly named function)

Comment: Hi @HoneyBadger, I also tried this but this query: SELECT product.name, SUM(sale.amount), SUM(forecast.amount) FROM product LEFT JOIN forecast ON product.id = forecast.product_id LEFT JOIN sale ON product.id = sale.product_id WHERE product.id=1 throws me SUM of sale.amount 108 and 90 of forecast so, that's not correct values...

Comment: Hi @ObchodHraček, HoneyBadger is right, but you also have to use `GROUP BY` with the grouping column, which in you case could be `product.id`.

Comment: The result throws me not correct result (by counting I figure it that throws me correct result multiplied by 2 or 3)..

Comment: please use dummy tables and dummy data with your expected results (not only just images)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joins are cumulative on way to get round this is to push one of the tables into a correlated sub query.

```
drop table if exists product,forecast,sale;

create table product(id int);
create table forecast(pid int,amt int);
create table sale(pid int, amt int);

insert into product values (1),(2);
insert into forecast values (1,100),(2,200);
insert into sale values
(1,10),(1,20),(2,10);

select p.id,
        (select sum(amt) from forecast f1 where f1.pid = p.id) famt,
        sum(s.amt) samt
from product p
join sale    s on s.pid = p.id
group by p.id;

+------+------+------+
| id   | famt | samt |
+------+------+------+
|    1 |  100 |   30 |
|    2 |  200 |   10 |
+------+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

Comment: Hi, your answer throwings me this error # 1054 - Unknown 'product.id' column in field list  - when I'm trying to call this SQL query on DB..

Comment: Works fine for my data just make sure you transpose the columns names in my query correctly. BTW it's always better to post sample data as text I cannot even read the images on my monitor..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
SELECT product.name, sum(sale.amount) as sale_sum, sum(forecast.amount) as sum_forecast
FROM product
LEFT JOIN forecast ON product.id = forecast.product_id
LEFT JOIN sale ON product.id = sale.product_id
group by product.name
order by product.name
;
```

?

Comment: The result throws me not correct result (by counting I figure it that throws me correct result multiplied by 2 or 3)..

Answer (score 0):

Try something like :

```
SELECT product.name, SUM(sale.amount), SUM(forecast.amount)
FROM product
LEFT JOIN forecast ON product.id = forecast.product_id
LEFT JOIN sale ON product.id = sale.product_id
GROUP BY product.id
```

Comment: The result throws me not correct result (by counting I figure it that throws me correct result multiplied by 2 or 3)..

Comment: @ObchodHraček do you try Left instead of Left Join ?

Comment: When I tried only "LEFT" it's not work - getting error..

Comment: @ObchodHraček What error are you getting?

Comment: from phpMyAdmin: # 1064 - Your syntax is some weird near 'forecast ON product.id = forecast.product_id LEFT JOIN sale ON product.id = s ...' on line 1

Comment: @ObchodHraček The error indicates as if you formulated your request incorrectly, copied and pasted this one :  `SELECT product.name, SUM(sale.amount), SUM(forecast.amount)
FROM product
JOIN forecast ON product.id = forecast.product_id
JOIN sale ON product.id = sale.product_id
GROUP BY product.id`

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate *before* joining:

```
SELECT p.name, s.amount, f.amount
FROM product p LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT s.product_id, SUM(s.amount) as amount
      FROM sales s
      GROUP BY s.product_id
     ) s
     ON s.product_id = p.id LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT f.product_id, SUM(f.amount) as amount
      FROM forecast f
      GROUP BY f.product_id
     ) f
     ON f.product_id = p.id;
```